# override user controls' methods

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my user control

```
public virtual void Test()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

And my main window

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

As you see that my main window already have inheritance window
so how do i override my Test void in MainWindow?

Comment: Really unclear what you're asking

Comment: Please explain in different way which everyone can understand..

Comment: public override void UserControlName.Test(){ ... } that did not work 4 me, it saidsi can't use public or override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking how to override a method of class X in another class Y that inherits from Z. That is not possible.

Your class `MainWindow` inherits from `Window`, and that means that `MainWindow`'s ancestor does not have a `Test` method defined.

If it is not defined in the ancestor, you cannot override it.

If you want to add a method or methods to several classes that inherited from different base classes, you could include those methods in an `interface` instead of a class. You can then make your other classes implement that interface:

```
public interface ITest
{
    void Test();
}

public class MyControl : Control, ITest
{
    public void Test()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MyControl Test");
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window, ITest
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void Test()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("MainWindow Test");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It happens because if you want to override your userControl method Test, a class should inherit this user control. For example method test in userControl:

```
public virtual void Test()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}
```

And to override:

```
public partial class MyClass : YourUserControlClass
{
    public override void Test()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message2");
    }
}
```